# Quitar letras de un string c#

Tags: c#, string

Tengo una variable tipo string el cual cuenta con letras y números, lo que necesito es quitarle todas las letras y dejarle sólo los números

**Ejemplo: (La cadena a la que le quiero quitar las letras)**

```
string cadena = "123A9K334PLH";
```

**El resultado debe estar así, es decir, sin letras, sólo los números:**

```
"1239334"
```

Comment: Intentaste algo? esto es bastante simple dentro de todo.

Comment: Si, acabo de intentar Reemplazar todas las letras con "", algo como cadenaNueva= cadena.Replace("A",""); y así con todas las letras, pero supongo que debería haber otra forma sin repetir tanto

Comment: Y... podrias usar una expresion regular... porque no agregas todo lo que intentas en tu pregunta?

Comment: Tambien podrias buscar las letras por codigo ascii...

Comment: Edita tu pegunta y agrega el código que has intentado, para que al menos quede constancia que te has esforzado como mencionas en el comentario

Answer (score 3):

Antes de darte código, tienes que saber que en la programación existen muchas maneras de resolver escenarios. Puedes emplear expresiones regulares, puedes recorrer cada caracter dentro de esa cadena y verificar el código ascii, entre otras cosas.

Es deber de todo desarrollador entablar una relación con la documentación de la tecnología que se está utilizando, así que toma: https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/

Luego que hayas terminado de leer eso, sigue con: https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/where-clause

Finalmente una lectura a: https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.char.isdigit?view=netframework-4.8

Si te saltas la lectura y vas de frente al código, estarás avanzando sin tener los conceptos clave instalados en tu C:\erebro. Haz es el esfuerzo para entender cómo es que funciona y verás que desarrollar se te hará más fácil.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string cadena = "123A9K334PLH";     
        //Aqui la magia de usar Linq y los métodos de la clase Char
        string result = string.Concat(cadena.Where(c => Char.IsDigit(c)));
        Console.WriteLine(result); //1239334
    }   
}
```